# how to re-level a floor

Tags: floor, foundation, leveling

i've had a foundation inspector look at my floor:

[image: here is the floor level survey]

as you can see there is quite a deviance on the right hand side.

he says that any future movement is likely to be limited; although, cosmetic distress is likely to develop over time. the foundation is of continuous perimeter, reinforced concrete, spread footing type. past (not by me) re-leveling had compromised some of the anchor bolts, but were fixed with some strong ties.

my question is how could the floor be re-leveled and how much is it likely to cost?

cheers,

Comment: If the units are inches, +2.4 and +1.7 are attention getting. And *if true* this indicates to me that previous "leveling" raised it too much in those places. Does the floor have a visible hump there? Personally I would not do further leveling unless forced to as a condition of sale. Sounds to me like the engineer is not recommending intervention.

Comment: cheers Jim. yep; inches. yep; big noticeable hump in the hallway :( yep; considering selling.... any idea of cost?

Comment: Where is this property located?

Comment: Was the previous leveling done with piers added only at the perimeter or were piers also added internally? Do you have documentation of what was done in the prior foundation work?

Comment: @yee379 I have seen where the floor drops like this before - leveling was done and the same thing happened again after 2 years. What is underneath the property (whats it built on), what is actually causing the drop off - I assume the house was level when it was originally built. If you are selling it - maybe it is worth the time and money. If not - maybe look into the situation a little more so you don't end up like the dog chasing the tail.

Comment: thanks @JimStewart @Ken; the property is in northern california (bay area) on a hill. the soil is 'highly expansive'. unfortunately i do not have any documentation on what was previously done.i guess my main question is whether i am looking at something that is 10's of thousands or 100's thousands to fix :( cheers!

Comment: The only way to find out about cost is to start getting estimates (maybe pre-estimates) from local engineering firms who develop plans and from contractors. Did this hump appear as the California drought was broken by heavy rains? What I am suggesting, of course, is that maybe the hump would go down as the soils in the area dry out. You don't want to spend a lot and then have a prospective buyer demand more, or have the work rendered irrelevant by a big rip on the Hayward fault.